# Subtract two datetime to get the number of days (python)

Tags: python, datetime

I have been wrapping my mind around this for the last two days, and I am on the verge of giving up.

I have a col named `Renewed_subscription`, format `datetime`. I need to get how many days are between today and the date when a person has to renew his subscription.

```
from datetime import datetime
dataset['DaysUntilSub'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: (pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') - str(dataset['Renewed_subscription'])).days, axis=1)
```

It throws the error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> C:\Report.py in ()
>
> --> 166 dataset['DaysUntilSub'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: (pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') - str(dataset['Renewed_subscription'])).days, axis=1)
>
> 168 #dataset['DaysUntilSub'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: (pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') - str(dataset['Renewed_subscription'])).days, axis=1)
>
> C:\Users\katep\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
>
> 4150                     if reduce is None:
>      4151                         reduce = True
>   -> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
>      4153             else:
>      4154                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)
>
> C:\Users\katep\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
>
> 4246             try:
>
> 4247                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>
> -> 4248                     results[i] = func(v)
>
> 4249                     keys.append(v.name)
>
> 4250             except Exception as e:
>
> C:\Report.py in (x)
>
> TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 42')

I will be very grateful if you could, please, point at my error, because I cannot proceed with the analysis because of it!

Comment: can you read you own question?! imagine us...

Comment: Sorry, I formatted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above mentioned, you don't want to cast `datetime` to string before subtraction. You can operate using simple `-` sign and find how many `days` later.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([datetime(1985, 4, 10), 
                   datetime(2010, 4, 10), 
                   datetime(2015, 4, 10), 
                   datetime(2017, 4, 10)], columns=['Renewed_subscription'])
# subtraction with today
df['DaysUntilSub'] = df['Renewed_subscription'].map(lambda x: (datetime.today() - x).days)
```

The dataframe outout

```
  Renewed_subscription  DaysUntilSub
0   1985-04-10  11695
1   2010-04-10  2564
2   2015-04-10  738
3   2017-04-10  7
```

And the same solution without a lambda:

```
def days_from_today(date):
    return (datetime.today() - date).days

df['DaysUntilSub'] = df['Renewed_subscription'].map(days_from_today)
```

Comment: the trick worked! Thank you so much! Two days before I realized that "No man is an island". Dear community, could you, please, suggest some reading on lambda? I think I lack of understanding of the logic behind the operator.

Comment: `lambda` is an inline function built-in for Python (see http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk). In this case, it basically takes each row of dataframe as an input `lambda x: ` then return output after colon which is `(datetime.today() - x).days`.

Comment: @Stephen, done! I have my doubts about the map function, too - yes, I am that amateur.

Comment: @eponkratova, actually you are not that amateur, because an amazing number of people will post something here, and will then not respond to feedback and will give no credit to the people who helped them.  I am sure that if you continue to try hard at asking good questions, and paying attention to the feedback given (be sure your formatting is good) you will do fine here on StackOverflow.  Good Luck.

Comment: @Stepen, thanks for the comments and edits :) And good luck @ eponkratova

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to subtract a string from a string.

The code pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') produces a string '2016-04-31' and the code str(dataset['Renewed_subscription']) converts the dataset to str. The minus operator for date set is not defined for string. I would recommend the following:
pd.Timestamp.today() - dataset['Renewed_subscription']

This will give you timedelta object. Now you can convert it to days by calling days function.
For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 16, 0, 0)
>>> b = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> v = b-a
>>> v.days
1674
>>>
```

I hope this helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to subtract a string from another string.

**'string' - 'other string'**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e61d76792339> in <module>()
----> 1 'string' - 'other string'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

You need to subtract the datetime objects from each other then convert the timedelta object to a string.  For example something like this:

```
a = datetime.datetime.now()
dataset['DaysUntilSub'] = dataset['Renewed_subscription'].apply(lambda x: (x - a).days, axis=1)
```

this assumes that your 'Renewed_subscription' is already a datetime object.  The resulting column in the dataframe will be a integer value for the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I adopted at the end, thank to @titipat, was:

```
import dataset

dataset['DaysUntilSub'] = dataset['Renewed_subscription'].map(
    lambda x: (x - datetime.today()).days)
```

Comment: First, if @titipat solved your problem, please consider accepting his answer as outlined in [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And once you have enough reputation you might also upvote his answer. Second, lambdas can be a hard concept.  But they are nothing more than an unnamed function with one parameter.  I added a bit more at the end of titipat's answer to show how the exact same thing can be done with a named function.  Hopefully he won't mind me editing his post....