# Getting differences in days-invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21/06/2018' (Python)

Tags: python

I need to get difference between "future" and current date in days.
AWS EC2 instance tag value:

```
     print tags["TerminateOn"]

     21/06/2018
```

current date:

```
today=datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print today
14/06/2018
```

Want to get difference in days

```
print int(tags["TerminateOn"]) -int(datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Error:

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21/06/2018'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract two datetime to get the number of days (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460584/subtract-two-datetime-to-get-the-number-of-days-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `TerminateOn` to a datetime object and then subtract.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
TerminateOn = "21/06/2018"
today=datetime.datetime.now()
TerminateOn = datetime.datetime.strptime(TerminateOn, "%d/%m/%Y")
print (TerminateOn - today)
```

**Output:**

```
5 days, 23:04:35.993000
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakes, how to leave only days, need to remove hours ?

Comment: `print( (TerminateOn - today).days )`